# dripping water from the shower area

Tags: leak, bathtub, tub

Just moved into our new rented apartment and having trouble keeping the water from dripping out the bath tub area.

the side of the shower curtain that is closer to the shower head is okay as we have secured it with a shower curtain clip. The side opposite has a ledge that extends beyond the end of the tub. The water that drips and splashes from the side flows down to the opposite side of the tub and onto the ledge and then drips on to the floor. Unfortunately, The shower curtain is not long enough to stretch this far out to be clipped on the other end too[image]. The only way I feel I can prevent water from flowing down and eventually dripping to the floor is if we created a slant (incline) to prevent the water from flowing down like it does now. But as mentioned before, we live in a rented apartment and can not make any structural changes to the bathroom. Any advise would be much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: +1 for the great diagram.  From the shape of your puddle the floor looks pretty flat.

Comment: short term solution: put a cloth on the side before the ledge and let a corner hang down in the tub

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can run a line of sealant from the wall to the edge of the bath, creating a route for the water to take into the bath. Sealant is easily removed, so this wouldn't count as a structural modification in my eyes.

This should do the job, provided your bath is flush with the ledge. Here's a little diagram in keeping with your own:

[image: Diagram]